# Shift/Reduce conflict in Bision

Tags: bison

This is how my grammar looks right now

```
Grammar

0 $accept: program $end

1 program: class_list

2 class_list: class
3           | class_list class

4 class: CLASS TYPEID '{' feature_list '}' ';'
5      | CLASS TYPEID INHERITS TYPEID '{' feature_list '}' ';'

6 feature_list: /* empty */
7             | feature
8             | feature_list feature

9 feature: OBJECTID '(' formal_list ')' ':' TYPEID '{' expr '}' ';'
10        | OBJECTID ':' TYPEID
11        | OBJECTID ':' TYPEID ASSIGN expr

12 formal_list: /* empty */
13            | formal
14            | formal_list ',' formal

15 formal: OBJECTID ':' TYPEID

16 expr: /* empty */
```

And I am getting shift reduce at state 9 and 14. Can someone explain what the shift reduce conflict is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is the ambiguity of feature_list. Is a single feature a feature_list (production 7) or an empty feature_list (6) followed by a feature (8)?

The definition of formal_list will also accept some unexpected strings (such as a list starting with a comma).

In the first case, you could just remove production 7. For formal_list, you could define optional_formal_list as empty or formal_list and then remove the empty production for formal_list.